# Update Cell Based on Corresponding Matrix Row/Col Names

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out a way to update a matrix based on what the row and column names of that matrix are. For example say if, while reading in data, the 4th row name and 3rd column name are on the same line of data, to add a value into the cell at [4,3]. I have tried to do this using the code below:

```
dfList <- c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5")

emptyMatrix <- data.frame()
myMatrix <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(dfList), nrow = length(dfList)))
colnames(myMatrix) <- dfList
rownames(myMatrix) <- dfList
myMatrix[is.na(myMatrix)] <- 0
myMatrix
  
dtMatrix <- structure(list(category = c("Opponent", "Opponent", "Opponent", 
                                        "Opponent", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P2", "Opponent", "Opponent", 
                                        "P1"), Event = c("Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Turnover", 
                                                         "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", 
                                                         "Intercepted Pass", "Bad Pass", "Good Pass"), Receiver = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    NA, NA, NA, "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P1", NA, NA, "P2")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  
myMatrix[rownames(myMatrix), colnames(myMatrix)] <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(dtMatrix)) {
  if (dtMatrix$category[i] %in% dfList && dtMatrix$Event == "Good Pass" && dtMatrix$Receiver[i] %in% dfList) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) {
      # print(paste("passer = ", dtMatrix$category[i]))
      # print(paste("rownames = ", rownames(myMatrix)))
      # print(paste("receiver = ", dtMatrix$Receiver[i]))
      # print(paste("colnames = ", colnames(myMatrix)))
        print(paste(rownames(myMatrix[j,])))
      # if (rownames(myMatrix[j,]) %in% dtMatrix$category[i] &
      #     colnames(myMatrix[j]) %in% dtMatrix$Receiver[i]) {
      if (dtMatrix$category[i] == rownames(myMatrix[j,]) & 
          dtMatrix$Receiver[i] == colnames(myMatrix[j,])) {
          
        print(paste("myMatrixUpdate is", myMatrix[rownames(myMatrix[j,]) ,colnames(myMatrix[j])]))
        myMatrix[rownames(myMatrix), colnames(myMatrix)] <- 1 + myMatrix[rownames(myMatrix), colnames(myMatrix)]
      }
    }
  }
}
myMatrix
dtMatrix

expectedOutput <- structure(list(P1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), P2 = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                                 P3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), P4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), P5 = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                      0, 1, 0)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the data in `dtMatrix`, I am trying to take each time a player (P1-P5, in this case) in the category column makes a good pass to another player (1-5) in the receiver column, and add and update that into the variable called `myMatrix`. I have tried to do this using that code, but this only creates a matrix in `myMatrix` filled with all 1's. I have also tried using `which(myMatrix == "P1", arr.ind = T)` to get the specific row/col of each player, but this returns blank. I thought about trying to build a matrix as the data is being read in from `dtMatrix`, but wasn't sure how to go about that, so I built it pre-reading in instead.

The expected output matrix is at the bottom of the code in a data frame called `expectedOutput`. Is there an easier way to go about this by grouping the names or some sort like that? Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah sorry, good catch that was a typo on my end copying over from a previous df. I will update it so it says "Good Pass" so the ```expectedOutput``` [2,1]  is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the rows with `'Good Pass'` and drop rows with `NA` value in `Receiver`. Count the number of rows for each `category` and `Receiver` values, if certain combinations are missing from `dfList` in the output we `complete` them and get the data in wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

dtMatrix %>%
  filter(Event == 'Good Pass' & !is.na(Receiver)) %>%
  count(category, Receiver) %>%
  complete(category = dfList, Receiver = dfList, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Receiver, values_from = n) %>%
  column_to_rownames('category')

#   P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
#P1  0  2  0  0  0
#P2  1  0  1  0  0
#P3  0  0  0  1  0
#P4  0  0  0  0  1
#P5  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks that was fast! And looks great. Two questions, first when you say using ```complete```  if combinations are missing in ```dfList```, does that mean if say there was a ```P6``` in the data itself, but not in ```dfList```, that ```complete``` would add a ```P6``` into the matrix? And 2nd question is kind of a second part to my original post, but is it possible to make an ```expectedOutput``` look like this from my next comment. It is the same style of my original question, essentially a continuation but just adding every scenario into the dtMatrix.

Comment: ```expectedOutput <- structure(list(P1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2 = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), P3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), P5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `Good Pass` = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Turnover = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"Opponent"), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: @samrizz4 Yes, if the `P6` is present in the data it will add it into the final matrix. For the other question I would suggest you to ask a separate question as that would require a different approach.